# Ellipsoid definition

Tags: ellipsoids

One of the definitions of an ellipsoid in Boyd & Vandenberghe's *Convex Optimization* is

$$E = \{ x_c + A u : \| u \|_2 \leq 1\}$$

where $A$ is square and non-singular. It is also stated that if $A$ is singular, then we get a degenerate ellipsoid.

Can we generalize this set, that is, does the set $E$ still remain an ellipsoid if we take $A$ to be non-square? Or is there a special name for such sets?

Comment: Yes, it is still an ellipsoid. The definition basically says that you map a unit ball to the range of $A$, which is by def. an ellipsoid. It is always a degenerate ellipsoid in the non-square cases.

Comment: @V.S.e.H.: if $A$ is wider than it is tall, the result doesn't need to be degenerate.

Comment: @Troposphere You might want to rethink.

Comment: @V.S.e.H.: Why? If, for example, $x_c=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $A = \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$, then $E$ becomes the usual closed unit ball in $\mathbb R^3$, which seems to be a perfectly good non-degenerate ellipsoid by the original defintion too.

Comment: @Troposphere Your $A$ represents a map from $\mathbb{R}^4$ onto $\mathbb{R}^3$, not from $\mathbb{R}^3$...

Comment: @V.S.e.H.: Indeed it does. It is _necessary_ for speaking about _any_ non-square $A$ in the first place that $u$ is going to live in a space of a different dimension than the space $E$ is a subset of.

Comment: @Troposphere You're right, if we agree on the definition that a degenerate ellipsoid has an empty interior (which it doesn't in your case).